# Relation between power and energy

Tags: energy, time, power

If I have an expression for the 'rated generator power' of a wind turbine, call it $P(t)$ how is the energy, that the wind turbine generator generate, related to the power $P(t)$?

> So:
>
> $$E(t)=\dots$$

Comment: Power can be interpreted as energy consumed per second. So if a device consumes energy 'E' in 't' seconds then the energy consumed per unit time ,i.e $\frac{E}{t}$, will give us the power.

Comment: Why not just $E(t) = \int_0^t P(t) dt$ ?

Answer (score 5):

From the [Wikipedia article on power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)) it states that

> power is the rate of doing work. It is the amount of energy consumed per unit time.

Therefore: $$P = \frac {dE}{dt}$$ and therefore (assume we start at $t = 0$) you can integrate to get:  $$E(t) = \int_0^t P (t)\ dt$$